# Next.js app throws an error on the server but not locally

Tags: node.js, deployment, next.js

I have been developping a Next app for quite a while now.

After the build, my app works just fine locally, but throws this on the server:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
at NextNodeServer.getEdgeFunctions (...node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:656:23)
at NextNodeServer.generateCatchAllMiddlewareRoute (...node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:991:22)
at NextNodeServer.generateRoutes (...node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:464:41)
at new Server (...node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:109:48)
at new NextNodeServer (...node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:62:9)
at NextServer.createServer (...node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:128:16)
at async ...node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:137:31
```

IMO this error message isn't really explicit...
The previous version of the worked just fine I changed it so much I don't really know where to look.

Of course I ran `npm install` btw.

I know that this is probably too little info to have a definite answer, but I have no idea of where I can look...

Comment: I have the same problem. This app used to work perfectly. I suspect that this started happening when we upgraded Next.js from 11.1.2 to 12.1.6. Did you also recently upgrade Next.js?

Comment: Looking at the code where the error occurs (`getEdgeFunctions`), it calls `const manifest = this.getMiddlewareManifest();` and then tries to get the keys of `manifest.functions`, but `manifest.functions` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

For us, the same thing occurred with our Next.JS applications running on AWS Beanstalk. After reverting Next.JS in the package.json to version 12.1.6 everything started working again.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, basically deleted node_modules, cache, .next folder, etc. and made a new clean install then a new build and it seems to work.

My guess is that it have something to do with cache from previous builds...

Answer (score 1):

It might be a problem with Webpack 5 at the time to build.

Here was a discussion about it: [TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object" with next dev server](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/26186)

I had been using Next.js v12.1.6 and now I updated to v12.2.0 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Delete node_modules, cache, .next folder, etc. and made a new clean install
then a new build.

It works for me and will work for you also